# Excel not responding alert and slow processing

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I am writing an Excel macro that calls another macro when run. However, when I run the first macro, Excel shows the "Excel Not Responding" message at the top of the window. Although the macro ultimately works and calls the other macro, it takes about 20 seconds for the whole process to complete and I am trying to figure out how to fix this.

This macro (code included below) is coded onto 5 individual worksheets; i.e. as you right click a worksheet and click "View Code," the code for this macro is listed there. The goal of this macro is to identify when a cell within a range of cells is changed and in turn call another macro to populate data into a cell. As mentioned, the process is working correctly on all sheets, however it takes around 20 seconds to actually run on a specific worksheet and the other 4 worksheets are doing the exact same thing. My goal was to have these macros work instantaneously as if they were both general macros on one worksheet. It seems however that when the code is input into the specific worksheet's code, this slows down the process a lot.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6:E60")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Date_Yes1
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub Date_Yes1()
    Dim rng1 As Range, c As Range, Sh As Worksheet
    
    Set Sh = ActiveSheet
    
    With Sh
        Set rng1 = .Range("E6:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    
        For Each c In rng1.Cells
            If c = "Yes" And .Range("C" & c.Row).Value2 = Blank Then .Range("C" & c.Row).Value2 = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code for `Date_Yes1`? The easy guess is the problem is there

Comment: date yes code has been added to the post

Comment: What Is `Blank` , a variable ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Blank is denoting that the cell is blank, that along with if a cell in column E says "Yes" will make the If true.

Comment: You probably want the `worksheet_change`  event and not `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

Comment: Also disabling screen updating and recalculation whilst the code runs will make quite  a big difference to performance. Remember to enable them again afterwards!